# Topic Modeling using Mallet Api for Java

Tags: java, nlp, mallet

Hi i have to do topic modeling using Mallet Java API but i am new to Mallet so i am finding it real difficult to understand the Mallet libraries and use them. Does anyone know any place where there might be some source code for topic modeling to understand the libraries?

Answer (score 4):

Did you check out the MALLET Topic Modeling developer's guide? It contains an example file that walks you through some of the options:

http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php

Rather than referencing the example file on the web page, download the latest MALLET development version (2.0.7rc1 as of this writing) and look in:

`src/cc/mallet/examples/TopicModel.java`,

The web page doesn't contain exactly the same script, and the distribution version is more hepful.

If you prefer not to touch Java at all you can do pretty well using the command line versions of the tools that don't require any Java coding:

http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php

Not all the options have command line flags to set them, but you can still do the basics.

Comment: Also, take a look at the tutorial slides from page 97 onwards: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/mallet-tutorial.pdf